# NEST won't allow me to add a func parameter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Okay, I have a weird issue and I'm not sure if it's just because they're funcs and funcs are quite new to me (the whole idea of a func annoys me a bit).

I need to call the exact same query twice, because I need 2 graphs/data sets. One for each parameter. Because I don't want to duplicate my query, I've added a func parameter with my class, so I can strongly typed select the correct property on my class.

```
SearchDescriptor<Stats> Query(SearchDescriptor<Stats> qc, Func<Stats, double> field)
{
    var query = qc
        .Aggregations(aggs => aggs
            .DateHistogram("histogram", d => d
                .Field(f => f.Timestamp)
                .FixedInterval("30m")
                .MinimumDocumentCount(1)
                .Aggregations(childAggs => childAggs
                    .Average("3", f => f
                        .Field(fi => field(fi))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Query(q =>
            q.Bool(b =>
                b.Filter(
                    f => f.MatchPhrase(mp => mp
                        .Field(fi => fi.Name)
                        .Query(name)
                    ),
                    f => f.DateRange(r => r
                        .Field(fi => fi.Timestamp)
                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
                        .LessThanOrEquals(DateTime.UtcNow)
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    return query;
}

var cpu = await GetByScrolling<Stats>(client, qc => Query(qc, fi => fi.CpuPercent));
var memory = await GetByScrolling<Stats>(client, qc => Query(qc, fi => fi.MemoryUsage));
```

This compiles and should work, but unfortunately the generated JSON turns out like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "3": {
        "avg": {
            "field": "field"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the value is `field`, which is definitely wrong. It's like the internal part of NEST does some kind of `.ToString()` on whatever argument is there, which is why it's returning `field` instead of what I put in my func.

Any idea if this is supposed to be like this? The `aggs` in my JSON also corresponds to the `.Aggregations(aggs => aggs` lambda naming.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, as I said, I am new to funcs and also `Expression`, which turns out is what I need. It doesn't actually evaluate the func - I need to give it an expression.

```
SearchDescriptor<Stats> Query(SearchDescriptor<Stats> qc, Expression<Func<Stats, double>> field)
{
    ......
}
```

and then give it the expression:

```
.Average("3", f => f
    .Field(field)
)
```

Then it evaluates it and works perfectly.